# ideahow to fit a piecewise Geyer model with three interaction distance in R pakage spatstat?

Tags: r, spatstat

I am using spatstat to analyze xylem conduit spatial distribution for cross sectional image of tree slice. someone suggest using Geyer function to model conduit spatial distribution. however, I donnot understand how to fit the model.

In a paper (Mencuccini et al,2010.A quantitive and statistical orbust method for the determination of xylem conduit spatial distribution. American Journal of Botany), the author suggested that conduit distribution be modeled by a piecewise Geyer model with three interaction distance over which conduit-to-conduit interaction takes place.  however, there are no such option in spatstat as "piecewise Geyer model".

> ppm(X~1, Geyer(r=0.05,sat=2))
>   is it right?

any one could help with the code to fit such an "piecewise Geyer model"?

reading the book, It seem that piecewise Geyer model looks like hybrid Gibbs model, the code is like:

> ppm(X~1, hybrid(hardcore(), Geyer(,), Geyer(,)))
>   now the question is, can I use twice Geyer saturation model in one hybrid function?

Answer (score 0):

I have briefly discussed this with the other spatstat authors.
The terminology “piecewise Geyer model” is not standard in the spatial point
process literatue. The cited paper (which we have not looked up) is likely
referring to the `BadGey` model in spatstat.

A useful alternative could be to consider hybrid models (of which this is an
example). This allows for incremental model improvement. See the spatstat
help page for `Hybrid` or more detailed examples in the hyprids paper referred
to in the spatstat citation `citation('spatstat')`.

Here is an example of `BadGey` both directly and as a Hybrid model, where
you can see that the parameter estimates are identical:

```r
library(spatstat)
ppm(swedishpines ~ 1, BadGey(c(5, 9), c(1,2)))
#> Stationary hybrid Geyer process
#> 
#> First order term:  beta = 0.04550482
#> 
#> Interaction radii:   c(5, 9)
#> Saturation parameters:   c(1, 2)
#> Fitted interaction parameters gamma_i
#>     [0,5)     [0,9) 
#> 0.8083960 0.5550427 
#> 
#> Relevant coefficients:
#> Interact.1 Interact.2 
#> -0.2127032 -0.5887103 
#> 
#> For standard errors, type coef(summary(x))
ppm(swedishpines ~ 1, Hybrid(Geyer(5, 1), Geyer(9, 2)))
#> Stationary Hybrid interaction
#> 
#> First order term:  beta = 0.04550482
#> 
#> Hybrid of 2 components: 'HybridComponent1' and 'HybridComponent2'
#> HybridComponent1:
#> Interaction:Geyer saturation process
#> Interaction distance:    5
#> Saturation parameter:    1
#> HybridComponent2:
#> Interaction:Geyer saturation process
#> Interaction distance:    9
#> Saturation parameter:    2
#> 
#> Fitted HybridComponent1 interaction parameter gamma: 0.808396
#> Fitted HybridComponent2 interaction parameter gamma: 0.5550427
#> 
#> Relevant coefficients:
#> HybridComponent1. HybridComponent2. 
#>        -0.2127032        -0.5887103 
#> 
#> For standard errors, type coef(summary(x))
```

Comment: Thanks Ege, your answer helps me alot.  I will read the book twice to figure out how to do the job.  The book is excellent, however, sometimes you would find it is difficult to find more reference case studies in it for coding. Jingming